# MySQL time between returning false and it should be true

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE
  MAKETIME(3,0,0) BETWEEN MAKETIME(23,0,0) AND MAKETIME(5,0,0)
```

is returning nothing And 3:00 is between 23:00 AND 5:00 time. Why is that can anyone explain me how to solve this problem?

Comment: 3 does not appear to be between 5 and 23

Comment: What Ed says. What you want is the time from *yesterday* 23:00.

Comment: How it is not ? this is time between
23:00 24:00 1:00 2:00 3:00 4:00 5:00 should be between 23:00 and 5:00

Comment: @Vuk Vasić: then any timestamp is between any other 2 timestamps

Comment: @VukVasić Think of it like this. If you have a table column containing values 23:00, 3:00, and 5:00, and you do an `ORDER BY` that column, would 3:00 appear between 23:00 and 5:00?

Comment: No it isn't i wrote down what is between 23:00 and 5:00. There is no other way to formulate this time period

Comment: What are the actual values being used here?  Even if you picked a value that was between 5 and 23 then you'd  just be returning every record in the table.

Comment: @Vuk Vasić: so is 1:00am between 21:00 and 21:01 ?

Comment: no it's not but 3am is between 11pm and 5am

Comment: @Vuk Vasić: well, it **is** between. Because 1am today is between 21:00 yesterday and 21:01 today, isn't it?

Comment: no it isn't because i am not comparing dates i am compering times

Comment: @Vuk Vasić: I don't see how 1am between 21:00 yesterday and 21:01 today is different from 3am between 23:00 yesterday and 5:00 today. Could you point to why in my example I cannot use "yesterday", but in your - you can?

Comment: I don't understand what are you talking about again i am comparing times and if there were no dates only times 3 AM MUST BE BETWEEN 11PM and 5 PM. For example you have a Pizza Club working from 11pm to 5am is it working at 3am or NOT ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42068/discussion-between-zerkms-and-vuk-vasic)

Comment: @VukVasić You've been told the answer. You don't have to like it, but it's the answer. Contesting reality isn't going to get you anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear what you're actually trying to do here, because even if 3 were between 5 and 23 your query would simply return every record in the table.

```
SELECT MAKETIME(3,0,0) BETWEEN MAKETIME(5,0,0) AND MAKETIME(23,0,0)
```

Returns 0, because 3 is not between 5 and 23.

```
SELECT MAKETIME(5,0,0) BETWEEN MAKETIME(3,0,0) AND MAKETIME(23,0,0)
```

Returns 1, because 5 is between 3 and 23.

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/17291/0)

Presumably you're trying to wrap into the previous day, in which case you can directly compare `datetime` values, but it's unclear given your question what fields/datatypes you're actually working with.

**Update:**
Based on your comment, I think you want 2 comparisons.  3 is not between 5 and 23, because time doesn't wrap across days.  But if you only care about the time portion you can handle it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE YourTime BETWEEN MAKETIME(23,0,0) AND MAKETIME(23,59,59)
   OR YourTime BETWEEN MAKETIME(0,0,0) AND MAKETIME(5,0,0)
```

Remember that `BETWEEN` is inclusive, so if 5am is your cutoff time you may want it to be `MAKETIME(4,59,59)` so it includes 4:59 but not 5:00

Comment: I am trying to compare working hours is the hotel for example working. I don't have which is the previous day i need to see if the hotel is working at 3 am or not understand ?

Comment: @Vuk Vasić: we understand that you don't have a strict criteria, but some vague that you cannot even apply consistently.

Comment: @VukVasić I think I understand what you're after, see updated.

Comment: @Goat CO: if you put numbers from my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252486/mysql-time-between-returning-false-and-it-should-be-true#comment30208154_20252486 then you'll get `true`, whereas OP expects `false` :-) OP needs someone to read his minds, since it's all "simple" for him: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13196062#13196062

Comment: Lol, and finally OP checked the answer that wouldn't fit into his requirements. That's soooooo funny )

Comment: @zerkms I was thinking OP wanted a fixed range of times, between 11 pm and 5am each night, so disregarding day my update makes sense, you can use it to find out if a given time is between those ranges, even though they span days.

Comment: It's not about your answer in particular, but OP's inconsistency. In the chat I've found that "day" doesn't span after 12pm. And according to OP it should have been obvious to us )

Answer (score 1):

Function [MAKETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_maketime) returns a time value calculated from the hour, minute, and second arguments:

```
mysql> SELECT MAKETIME(3,0,0),MAKETIME(23,0,0),MAKETIME(5,0,0)
       -> '03:00:00', '23:00:00', '05:00:00'
```

and, of course, 3 is not BETWEEN 23 AND 5 and it will return false. But yes, 3AM actually is between 11PM and 5AM, so how could you solve this?

Let's consider 23 as your START_TIME, and 5 as your END_TIME.

Since START_TIME has to happen before END_TIME, if this is not the case (23>5) that means that the interval rolls over the next day.

I would try with a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE
  (MAKETIME(START_TIME,0,0)<=MAKETIME(END_TIME,0,0) AND MAKETIME(3,0,0) BETWEEN MAKETIME(START_TIME,0,0) AND MAKETIME(END_TIME,0,0))
  OR
  (MAKETIME(START_TIME,0,0)>MAKETIME(END_TIME,0,0) AND NOT (MAKETIME(3,0,0) BETWEEN MAKETIME(START_TIME,0,0) AND MAKETIME(END_TIME,0,0)))
```